# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'WinDLL' from 'ctypes' (/var/lang/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, aws-lambda

I'm trying to generate a graph with matplotlib in python lambda function. i imported a layer with the library mathplotlib, but it doesn't work.
The idea is generate a graph, save it like temp file and upload to S3.

When i run the code, the output is:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'WinDLL' from 'ctypes' (/var/lang/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Help!

I need intall another library? I saw that is a problem with numpy library, but i don't know.

Exist another library to generate graphs?

Comment: Please use a meaningfull title regarding YOUR issue

Comment: Title changed azro!

Comment: Your question is missing the code that generated the error. The error (cause) is pretty clear, but one needs the context in order to provide an answer.. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
for more asking related details.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any luck? - @NicolasParra

Comment: I changed the python version from 3.7 to 3.6 and it worked

Answer (score 3):

I assume you used a windows OS to package your python libraries (via virtualenv) and uploaded them as a zip file in the create function section of AWS-Lambda.

AWS is linux based so the incompatibility might stem from the fact that you packaged your libraries on windows.

Basically, you would need to do the packaging in a linux machine. Maybe using a free tier version of ec2-linux. Moreover, the matplotlib library has it's own compatibility issues so there is no real guarantee that this approach will work.

Hope this helps