# How do I transfer a file from a AWS EC2 Amazon Linux Virtual Env to local (windows)?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, amazon-ec2, scikit-learn, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to use Sklearn on a Python Lambda function. Since Sklearn is not native, I need to upload the library and its dependencies in a layer. One such dependency, Numpy, is bigger than I can upload but, fortunately, AWS already provides a Scipy, Numpy layer (AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x), so yay! Therefore, I thought I need to create a layer with the remaining libraries and use both layers on my lambda function.
Thus, I've created a layer with the libraries (joblib, threadpoolctl, scikit-learn and sklearn) on my windows, uploaded it and called the function, which didn't work. Mother Google told me it was due to compatibility issues (windows-linux)¹.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'WinDLL' from 'ctypes' (/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Finally, I’ve decided to use a Linux Instance, install Python, the remaining libraries and then upload the Lambda layer. I got an "Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type" and did the steps described below² (please, be kind to Linux newbs):

**On my windows cmd**

```
cd C:/path_to_aws.pem
ssh -i "file.pem" ec2-user@ec2-x.region.compute.amazonaws.com

sudo yum update
sudo su
yum install openssl-devel
yum install libffi-devel
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz
tar -xf Python-3.8.3.tgz
cd Python-3.8.3
sudo su
./configure --enable-optimizations
nproc
make -j 1
sudo make altinstall
exit
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3.8 get-pip.py
sudo su
python3.8 -m venv biblio/env
source ~/biblio/env/bin/activate
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install joblib
pip install threadpoolctl
pip install scikit-learn
pip install sklearn
zip -r python38_lib.zip /biblio
```

**ISSUE:** Now I have the library installed in a Linux machine, but how do I get it to my computer from the local environment? I know how to get it if it is on the instance (outside env)³:

```
scp -i " file.pem " ec2-user@ec2-x.region.compute.amazonaws.com:/path/file.zip C:/
```

If you can help me with the initial problem, that is, running Sklearn on Lambda, with a shorter and painless solution: <3! Otherwise, can you help me get the library.zip file to my windows?

Thank you kindly.

¹ [Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'WinDLL' from 'ctypes' (/var/lang/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329892/unable-to-import-module-lambda-function-cannot-import-name-windll-from-cty)

² https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-python3-boto3/

³ https://medium.com/@dearsikandarkhan/files-copying-between-aws-ec2-and-local-d07ed205eefa

Comment: Check this out. https://github.com/ryfeus/lambda-packs/tree/master/LightGBM_sklearn_scipy_numpy

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I need a python 3 version of these libraries...

Answer (score 0):

## **TL;DR, I've built the layer for you. You can download it through this gdrive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AhfXFdOFoTLOAs0kLFfxS3Wl2mbaYRzq/view?usp=sharing). NB: NumPy is included.**

It's easier to build a lambda layer by using the [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/).

```
# serverless.yml

service: serverless-example

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    layer: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  profile: dummy

functions:
  dummy:
    handler: dummy.handler
```

```
# requirements.txt

joblib==0.16.0
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
scikit-learn==0.23.1
```

Simply do `sls package -p pkg`, then the layer zip named `pythonRequirements.zip` will be in `pkg` directory.