# How to make a lighter SciPy package for AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda restricts packages to be less than 50MB zipped. I need to use `scipy` for my workflow which is a large package, so I'm trying to trim it down so I can use it within lambda without having to use container images or anything like that since I'm not as familiar with it. And lambda is the ideal solution for our business' problem so I can't switch to something else.

Here's what I've done so far:

### 1 - Make the zip file

With a `requirements.txt` file that just has `scipy`, I ran the following code in my `aws-layer` folder:

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target aws-layer/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages`

This downloads both the `scipy` and `numpy` packages. From here I went into the `scipy` folder and deleted folders other than `scipy.sparse` and `scipy.optimize` since those are the only two I need. Next I ran `zip -r9 lambda-layer.zip .` to make a zip folder - the total size of this was 37MB so within the limits for AWS.

### 2 - Create the lambda function

I just created a dummy AWS Lambda function with runtime of python3.11 to match my zipped packages. I added lines to import the applicable packages so that I could confirm everything is working appropriately once it's setup. When I try running this before adding my layer, I get an error `No module named 'scipy'` as expected.

```
import json
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint, Bounds
import numpy

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

### 3 - Import the zip file as a layer and add to the Lambda function

In AWS Lambda I created a new layer where I uploaded the zip file, and made sure to make the runtime python3.11 to match the function.

### 4 - Test the code; get error

And here is where I'm getting errors. I think the layer-upload process itself worked because I no longer get a message saying `scipy` doesn't exist. Instead, it seems like there's an issue with `numpy` which is a dependency of `scipy`.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': \n\nIMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\n\nPlease note and check the following:\n\n  * The Python version is: Python3.11 from \"/var/lang/bin/python3.11\"\n  * The NumPy version is: \"1.21.6\"\n\nand make sure that they are the versions you expect.\nPlease carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.\n\nOriginal error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'\n",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "bde94bb7-ba45-4019-bf0f-81ef08c7124b",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I've followed the link that they suggested and I can't figure out what's going on or how to fix it. It seems like maybe there's an issue with `Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`, but I didn't delete anything from `numpy` before I made a zip folder, only `scipy`. So I'm not sure why any `numpy` module would be missing.

---

### 5 - Potential solution: use built-in `pandas` layer which has `numpy`

Lambda has a built-in layer `AWSSDKPandas-Python311`. When I make a new function and add this as a layer, I'm able to run `import numpy` just fine. However, I'm unable to add in the trimmed `scipy` layer (even after removing `numpy`) because the built-in pandas layer already takes up too much space.

---

So now I'm left brainstorming potential solutions:

1. The easiest would be to just figure out the `numpy` error that's happening in my 4th step when I test the custom package. If anyone could help me solve this I'd greatly appreciate it.
2. Slim the custom `scipy`-only package even further so that I can use both the `AWSSDKPandas-Python311` layer and my custom `scipy` layer, but I'm not sure if this is feasible. I'd have to do more research on what exactly I can remove from my `scipy` layer.
3. Since any single lambda function can only use 262144000 bytes, maybe I can make a `scipy`-only package in one lambda function, and the built-in `pandas` package in another lambda function, and then somehow combine them in a third function? Can someone tell me if this is possible?
4. Suck it up and learn how to use container images. I'm not sure where to start there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html) to get away the 50MB limit. I've built the `scipy` layer for you. You can download it through this google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Eh-c2UHbFj2b76NFFCfqCiE-T9xzXcP/view?usp=sharing). This layer is for the `python3.11` runtime. If you don't trust my code, you can follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62884844/10692493) to build it yourself.

Test code:

```py
import json
import scipy
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint, Bounds
import numpy

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print(f"scipy: {scipy.__version__}")
    print(f"numpy: {numpy.__version__}")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Test result:

```
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: a051ddd1-d54c-4709-be73-0b596d87ee7f Version: $LATEST
scipy: 1.12.0
numpy: 1.26.4
END RequestId: a051ddd1-d54c-4709-be73-0b596d87ee7f
REPORT RequestId: a051ddd1-d54c-4709-be73-0b596d87ee7f  Duration: 1.95 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 119 MB Init Duration: 1532.75 ms

Request ID
a051ddd1-d54c-4709-be73-0b596d87ee7f
```