# import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas' error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a layer in aws for pandas, added this layer into my lambda function. but the code return an error Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas'. what is the issue for this

My system is windows 11 and I am using python 3.9 and the following commands are used for creating zip file that contains pandas
mkdir python
cd python
pip3 install pandas -t .
Compress-Archive -Path . -DestinationPath pandas_layer.zip

Comment: Amazon provides AWS SDK for Pandas layers for you, which includes Pandas: https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/layers.html The reason your layer isn't working is because there is a lot more to building a Pandas layer than just doing `pip install`, you have to include binary linked dependencies, which you can't do easily on a Windows machine.

Answer (score -1):

I've built the `pandas` layer for you. You can download it through this google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eeIR7VqYn5SJ52haidpi4vZcOMuJjGLP/view?usp=sharing). This layer is for the x86_64 `python3.11` runtime. If you don't trust my code, you can follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62884844/10692493) to build it yourself.

Test code:

```py
import json
import pandas

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print(f"pandas: {pandas.__version__}")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Test result:

```
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 877b0199-a9f2-4b94-bec4-b6520ffdebfb Version: $LATEST
pandas: 2.2.1
END RequestId: 877b0199-a9f2-4b94-bec4-b6520ffdebfb
REPORT RequestId: 877b0199-a9f2-4b94-bec4-b6520ffdebfb  Duration: 2.22 ms   Billed Duration: 3 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 119 MB Init Duration: 2196.50 ms

Request ID
877b0199-a9f2-4b94-bec4-b6520ffdebfb
```

Comment: Not only pandas, I can't import any packages using layers.